Edit custom meta box value on post edit page
I'm new to this please bear with me a little.
I am trying to edit how the value of a custom meta boxes is display to my WordPress post edit page. I'm using a plugin this pulling the listings for the IDX, however, it's pulling the price with currency symbol and commas. I want it to be numbers only on WordPress post edit page.
This is the code I wrote based on what I saw with the plugin code, but nothing is happening. Please help.
function listing_details_metabox() {
wp_nonce_field( 'wp_listings_metabox_save', 'wp_listings_metabox_nonce' );

global $post;

$property_details = $_POST['wp_listings'];

if ( null == $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
}

$price = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', get_post_meta( $post_id, '_listing_price', true));
if ( ! isset( $property_details['col1']['_listing_price'] ) ) {
    
?>

<p>
<label for="wp_listings[_listing_price]" >Price 2</label>
<input type="text" name="wp_listings[_listing_price]" value="<?php if ( isset ( $price ) ) echo $price; ?>"$
</p>

<?php
}

}

enter image description here

edit your question to explain which plugin you use and how to setup this field.

I'm using IMPress for IDX Broker plugin which creates a custom post type call listing. It automatically upload and update listings from the IDX.

POST your full code
